# Docker installation issues on CentOS 7.1

Tags: docker, failed-installation

I was trying to install docker with these instructions:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/

It went well without any error, just one warning. But nothing seems to be get installed. I tried it a few times with different approaches on two different machines. Result was the same. It did not install.

Here is the console output:

```
[root@myhostname ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
[root@myhostname ~]# uname -r
3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64

[root@myhostname ~]# cat  /etc/yum.repos.d/docker.repo 
[dockerrepo]
name=Docker Repository
baseurl=https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/$releasever/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://yum.dockerproject.org/gpg

[root@myhostname ~]#  sudo yum install docker-engine
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, rhnplugin
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
dockerrepo                                                                                                   | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
dockerrepo/7/primary_db                                                                                      |  11 kB  00:00:00
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
apel-7-x86_64                                                                                                | 1.0 kB  00:00:00
epel-7-x86_64                                                                                                | 1.5 kB  00:00:00
ipel-7-x86_64                                                                                                | 1.0 kB  00:00:00
spacewalk-client-el7-x86_64                                                                                  | 1.2 kB  00:00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package docker-engine.x86_64 0:1.10.1-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: docker-engine-selinux >= %{epoch}:1.10.1-1.el7.centos for package: docker-engine-1.10.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdevmapper.so.1.02(DM_1_02_97)(64bit) for package: docker-engine-1.10.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit) for package: docker-engine-1.10.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: docker-engine-1.10.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package device-mapper-libs.x86_64 7:1.02.93-3.el7_1.1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: device-mapper-libs = 7:1.02.93-3.el7_1.1 for package: 7:device-mapper-1.02.93-3.el7_1.1.x86_64
---> Package device-mapper-libs.x86_64 7:1.02.107-5.el7_2.1 will be an update
---> Package docker-engine-selinux.noarch 0:1.10.1-1.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package systemd-libs.x86_64 0:208-20.el7_1.6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: systemd-libs = 208-20.el7_1.6 for package: systemd-208-20.el7_1.6.x86_64
---> Package systemd-libs.x86_64 0:219-19.el7_2.4 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package device-mapper.x86_64 7:1.02.93-3.el7_1.1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: device-mapper = 7:1.02.93-3.el7_1.1 for package: 7:device-mapper-event-1.02.93-3.el7_1.1.x86_64
---> Package device-mapper.x86_64 7:1.02.107-5.el7_2.1 will be an update
---> Package systemd.x86_64 0:208-20.el7_1.6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: systemd = 208-20.el7_1.6 for package: systemd-sysv-208-20.el7_1.6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd = 208-20.el7_1.6 for package: systemd-python-208-20.el7_1.6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd = 208-20.el7_1.6 for package: libgudev1-208-20.el7_1.6.x86_64
---> Package systemd.x86_64 0:219-19.el7_2.4 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: kmod >= 18-4 for package: systemd-219-19.el7_2.4.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package device-mapper-event.x86_64 7:1.02.93-3.el7_1.1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: device-mapper-event = 7:1.02.93-3.el7_1.1 for package: 7:lvm2-libs-2.02.115-3.el7_1.1.x86_64
---> Package device-mapper-event.x86_64 7:1.02.107-5.el7_2.1 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: device-mapper-event-libs = 7:1.02.107-5.el7_2.1 for package: 7:device-mapper-event-1.02.107-5.el7_2.1.x86_64
---> Package kmod.x86_64 0:14-10.el7 will be updated
---> Package kmod.x86_64 0:20-5.el7 will be an update
---> Package libgudev1.x86_64 0:208-20.el7_1.6 will be updated
---> Package libgudev1.x86_64 0:219-19.el7_2.4 will be an update
---> Package systemd-python.x86_64 0:208-20.el7_1.6 will be updated
---> Package systemd-python.x86_64 0:219-19.el7_2.4 will be an update
---> Package systemd-sysv.x86_64 0:208-20.el7_1.6 will be updated
---> Package systemd-sysv.x86_64 0:219-19.el7_2.4 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package device-mapper-event-libs.x86_64 7:1.02.93-3.el7_1.1 will be updated
---> Package device-mapper-event-libs.x86_64 7:1.02.107-5.el7_2.1 will be an update
---> Package lvm2-libs.x86_64 7:2.02.115-3.el7_1.1 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: lvm2-libs = 7:2.02.115-3.el7_1.1 for package: 7:lvm2-2.02.115-3.el7_1.1.x86_64
---> Package lvm2-libs.x86_64 7:2.02.130-5.el7_2.1 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package lvm2.x86_64 7:2.02.115-3.el7_1.1 will be updated
---> Package lvm2.x86_64 7:2.02.130-5.el7_2.1 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: device-mapper-persistent-data >= 0.5.5-1 for package: 7:lvm2-2.02.130-5.el7_2.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package device-mapper-persistent-data.x86_64 0:0.4.1-2.el7 will be updated
---> Package device-mapper-persistent-data.x86_64 0:0.5.5-1.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Conflict: systemd-219-19.el7_2.4.x86_64 conflicts initscripts < 9.49.28-1
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package initscripts.x86_64 0:9.49.24-1.el7 will be updated
---> Package initscripts.x86_64 0:9.49.30-1.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Conflict: systemd-219-19.el7_2.4.x86_64 conflicts dracut < 033-243
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package dracut.x86_64 0:033-241.el7_1.5 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: dracut = 033-241.el7_1.5 for package: dracut-config-rescue-033-241.el7_1.5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: dracut = 033-241.el7_1.5 for package: dracut-network-033-241.el7_1.5.x86_64
---> Package dracut.x86_64 0:033-360.el7_2 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package dracut-config-rescue.x86_64 0:033-241.el7_1.5 will be updated
---> Package dracut-config-rescue.x86_64 0:033-360.el7_2 will be an update
---> Package dracut-network.x86_64 0:033-241.el7_1.5 will be updated
---> Package dracut-network.x86_64 0:033-360.el7_2 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

====================================================================================================================================
 Package                                 Arch             Version                           Repository                         Size
====================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 docker-engine                           x86_64           1.10.1-1.el7.centos               apel-7-x86_64                     9.6 M
Updating:
 dracut                                  x86_64           033-360.el7_2                     centos-7-updates-x86_64           311 k
 initscripts                             x86_64           9.49.30-1.el7                     centos-7-base-x86_64              429 k
Installing for dependencies:
 docker-engine-selinux                   noarch           1.10.1-1.el7.centos               apel-7-x86_64                      28 k
Updating for dependencies:
 device-mapper                           x86_64           7:1.02.107-5.el7_2.1              centos-7-updates-x86_64           252 k
 device-mapper-event                     x86_64           7:1.02.107-5.el7_2.1              centos-7-updates-x86_64           167 k
 device-mapper-event-libs                x86_64           7:1.02.107-5.el7_2.1              centos-7-updates-x86_64           169 k
 device-mapper-libs                      x86_64           7:1.02.107-5.el7_2.1              centos-7-updates-x86_64           304 k
 device-mapper-persistent-data           x86_64           0.5.5-1.el7                       centos-7-base-x86_64              350 k
 dracut-config-rescue                    x86_64           033-360.el7_2                     centos-7-updates-x86_64            49 k
 dracut-network                          x86_64           033-360.el7_2                     centos-7-updates-x86_64            90 k
 kmod                                    x86_64           20-5.el7                          centos-7-base-x86_64              114 k
 libgudev1                               x86_64           219-19.el7_2.4                    centos-7-updates-x86_64            65 k
 lvm2                                    x86_64           7:2.02.130-5.el7_2.1              centos-7-updates-x86_64           1.0 M
 lvm2-libs                               x86_64           7:2.02.130-5.el7_2.1              centos-7-updates-x86_64           872 k
 systemd                                 x86_64           219-19.el7_2.4                    centos-7-updates-x86_64           5.1 M
 systemd-libs                            x86_64           219-19.el7_2.4                    centos-7-updates-x86_64           357 k
 systemd-python                          x86_64           219-19.el7_2.4                    centos-7-updates-x86_64            98 k
 systemd-sysv                            x86_64           219-19.el7_2.4                    centos-7-updates-x86_64            52 k

Transaction Summary
====================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package  (+ 1 Dependent package)
Upgrade  2 Packages (+15 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 19 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
No Presto metadata available for centos-7-updates-x86_64
No Presto metadata available for centos-7-base-x86_64
(1/19): device-mapper-1.02.107-5.el7_2.1.x86_64.rpm                                                          | 252 kB  00:00:00
(2/19): device-mapper-event-1.02.107-5.el7_2.1.x86_64.rpm                                                    | 167 kB  00:00:00
(3/19): device-mapper-event-libs-1.02.107-5.el7_2.1.x86_64.rpm                                               | 169 kB  00:00:00
(4/19): device-mapper-libs-1.02.107-5.el7_2.1.x86_64.rpm                                                     | 304 kB  00:00:00
(5/19): device-mapper-persistent-data-0.5.5-1.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                 | 350 kB  00:00:00
warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/apel-7-x86_64/packages/docker-engine-1.10.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA512 Signature, key ID 2c52609d: NOKEY
Public key for docker-engine-1.10.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm is not installed
(6/19): docker-engine-1.10.1-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm                                                         | 9.6 MB  00:00:01
(7/19): docker-engine-selinux-1.10.1-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm                                                 |  28 kB  00:00:00
(8/19): dracut-033-360.el7_2.x86_64.rpm                                                                      | 311 kB  00:00:00
(9/19): dracut-config-rescue-033-360.el7_2.x86_64.rpm                                                        |  49 kB  00:00:00
(10/19): dracut-network-033-360.el7_2.x86_64.rpm                                                             |  90 kB  00:00:00
(11/19): initscripts-9.49.30-1.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                | 429 kB  00:00:00
(12/19): kmod-20-5.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                                            | 114 kB  00:00:00
(13/19): libgudev1-219-19.el7_2.4.x86_64.rpm                                                                 |  65 kB  00:00:00
(14/19): lvm2-2.02.130-5.el7_2.1.x86_64.rpm                                                                  | 1.0 MB  00:00:00
(15/19): lvm2-libs-2.02.130-5.el7_2.1.x86_64.rpm                                                             | 872 kB  00:00:00
(16/19): systemd-219-19.el7_2.4.x86_64.rpm                                                                   | 5.1 MB  00:00:01
(17/19): systemd-libs-219-19.el7_2.4.x86_64.rpm                                                              | 357 kB  00:00:00
(18/19): systemd-python-219-19.el7_2.4.x86_64.rpm                                                            |  98 kB  00:00:00
(19/19): systemd-sysv-219-19.el7_2.4.x86_64.rpm                                                              |  52 kB  00:00:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                               1.5 MB/s |  19 MB  00:00:13


Public key for docker-engine-selinux-1.10.1-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm is not installed
[root@myhostname ~]# sudo service docker start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  docker.service
Failed to issue method call: Unit docker.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

INDEED:

[root@myhostname tmp]# ls /etc/systemd/system/docker.service
ls: cannot access /etc/systemd/system/docker.service: No such file or directory

Comment: Seems the docker GPG key isn't imported, run `rpm --import https://yum.dockerproject.org/gpg` first and install docker again

Comment: @nos supplied the correct answer. I had the same problem and his suggestion solved it. I suggest you make this an answer (not a comment) so that it can be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue and for me "rpm --import https://yum.dockerproject.org/gpg" didn;t work.

"yum clean all" worked for me. Looks like there was something wrong with the cache. After clean up it worked fine.